# iOS Twilio Receive Incoming SMS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, twilio

I am developing an iOS messaging app that uses Twilio to send and receive SMS and MMS. The tutorial on Twilio about the iOS client seems to only cover outgoing and incoming calls. I understand that sending an SMS/MMS would mean that I send a HTTP request to my server, in which my server sends the request to Twilio in order to complete the sending. However, how would I receive messages on my app?

I know that Twilio numbers have web hooks that execute when the number receives this message, but how would I get this message to my app. I don't believe that there are delegate methods included like the voice ones. The only solution that I could think of right now would be to use push notifications from my server to the phone. Is there any other possible way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recently in a similar situation to yours, but my app only cares about receiving a response within a 2 minute window while the app is opened.

Regardless, I would say that your best options include 1) push notifications, 2) sockets (probably via Socket.io), or 3) background polling. If you plan to have your application receive the message agnostic of its state (open, closed, etc), then I would highly suggest using push notifications. I'm using Parse as my Twilio backend and it makes creating and working with push notifications a breeze :)